# How can I access local svn repository on my computer?

Tags: svn, repository, localhost

Not an expert in svn right now. I created a local repository. When I would browse to the folder in Windows Explorer, it would always be empty. Found out that you need apache webserver to access the repository using file:/// protocol? (of course I can access the repository from visual studio).

I want to access the respository directly. The problem is, I created repository in folder other than apache root folder (c:\reposiataries\test). Can some guide me how can I access this repository either in windows explorer or internet explorer? I have xampp install, that is Apache, Mysql, PHP.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use an svn client like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to checkout the repository.

Comment: I am using Akkhsvn at the moment to see the repositorary from Visual Studio. I am just curious, how can I access the repositary without an client. I dnot need to modify anything, just want to see the file.

Comment: for this, you could look at the options that the collabnet distribution has to offer (using httpd from apache) as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your repo directly in your filesystem. If however you want to use apache to serve your repo (you don't have to), you need some apache modules or alternatively you could look into the collabnet subversion distribution: http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a webserver to access the repository. You can just point your client (I used [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)) to the repository folder itself. For me, the "my-repository" repo was on the C:\ drive, in `C:\csvn\data\repositories\my-repository`.

[image: SVN Checkout from context menu]

[image: Checkout dialog with the URL pointing to local folder]

After this, you should have a working copy of the data in said repository. You can commit, revert, view logs, etc.